# Partial derivative of a linear regression with correlated predictors

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression, regression-coefficients, derivative

Let's set up the situation of having some $Y$ that I think depends on a linear combination of $X_1$ and $X_2$. I could fit a regression model:

$$y_i = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{i1} + \beta_2x_{i2}$$

We could write this as a function of the predictor variables:

$$y(x_1, x_2) = \beta_0 + \beta_1x_{1} + \beta_2x_{2}$$

Then we would interpret the coefficients as being the partial derivatives.

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_1} = \beta_1$$

$$\dfrac{\partial y}{\partial x_2} = \beta_2$$

This is consistent with our usual idea that, as we increase $x_1$ by one unit and leave $x_2$ alone, $y$ changes by $\beta_1$.

However, what if $X_1$ and $X_2$ are correlated? In that case, if we increase $x_1$ by one unit, $x_2$ should change by some amount.

I've gotten as far as thinking that it has something to do with the inner product of $\big(\beta_1, \beta_2\big)$ with itself with respect to the covariance matrix of $X_1$ and $X_2$:

$$\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 & \beta_2
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\sigma_{1,1} & \sigma_{1,2}\\
\sigma_{2,1} & \sigma_{2,2}
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
\beta_1 \\
\beta_2
\end{pmatrix}
$$

Thoughts? How does the intercept play into this? Certainly the intercept should drop out, but where?

(There should be $\widehat{\text{hats}}$ all over the place, yes.)

Comment: Yes, please do add the hats in the $y$ and $\beta$s

Comment: Your characterization of "correlated" sounds more like *causally linked.*  I suppose one way to interpret it would be "if I predicted $X_2$ from $X_1$ using linear regression, and then changed $x_1$ and $x_2$ simultaneously in a way consistent with that prediction, how much would the prediction of $Y$ change?"  If that's your intention, what you need is a *directional derivative.*  It gives a nice, simple solution, because it's just the (intuitively obvious) linear combination of the $\hat\beta_i.$

Answer (score 1):

The coefficients in a multiple linear regression are by definition *conditional* coefficients. If you want the *marginal* relationship, the general answer is to integrate over the distribution of $x_1$ and $x_2$. However, typically, the distribution is unspecified, and people use the empirical distribution instead. In the linear regression case, I think this reduces to simply fitting the model of one variable without the other.